# How to perform 'cheap' scale of the entire screen in D2D?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, direct2d

I am working on a touch screen application (WinRT) and currently draw some graphics to the screen. Because it is touch, I want to enable pinch-to-zoom for scaling the entire content. For a better experience, I only want to redraw the graphics, once the pinch gesture is complete. For the intermediate scalings, I would like to reuse the current bitmap, and perform (if possible) a gpu-only scaling (enlarge bitmap).
Basically, I want to do exactly what iOS and Windows Phone have been doing for years now.

How can I implement this in Direct2D?

As a bonus, If you know a good ressource for reading on Direct2D, please tell me. The MSDN documentation is really poor and I have to hunt different blogs and magazine articles to learn :(

What I tried so far:

```
m_target->SetTransform(
        D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale(
            D2D1::Size(1.5f, 1.5f),
            D2D1::Point2F(500.0f, 500.0f))
        );
```

However, if I do this for interactive elements (like page zoom-in/zoom-out), all objects are rendered (which is also slow).
Another option could be to draw into a BITMAP and use that as the base for the transforms. However, I am not sure if this is a good approach.
Note: I am currently debugging on a Desktop but want to target tablets. I have to consider that tablets are orders of magnitude slower. That's why I try to optimize this functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-766T, you should mention what you have tried.

Comment: @J.N. updated. I watched the build presentation. However, that did not help. I am looking for a good book or detailed guideline because I just started using Direct2D (no earlier DX experience).

Comment: What exactly are you rendering that makes redrawing so slow? Any device nowadays can render high end graphics at 20 fps. As JN said, we need more details about what you are rendering and what you tried.